# VSCode - Assign "double click" to a keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I perform a "search all" in VSCode, it displays a screen with all the occurrences of the searched item, highlighted. If one double-clicks on a highlighted occurrence, then they're taken to the location of said occurrence.

I'd prefer not to use my mouse to double-click on the highlighted words, and instead bring my cursor over the occurrence and then hit some sort of "double click" keyboard shortcut.

Does anybody know if this is possible? I know that it's possible in Sublime Text!